# How to make an object move along a user-defined line in Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

My program allows the user to click anywhere on the window, and when hitting Enter, it traces the line along those points. Also, when pressing space, it draws a triangle at the first point, and I want it to move along the entire line to the end, then goes back to the start, and repeats.

I got the line tracing and drawing the triangle on the start point to work, and I even got the translation movement to work. My only problem is that it just keeps moving bottom-right no matter how the line is. It must be how I'm getting the direction, but I don't know what's wrong.

First here's how I draw the triangle. The user-defined points are defined in a glm::vec3 variable called controlPoints. So I create the triangle on the 1st point (for which it then gets passed into the VBO, binded to the VAO, and so on [triangleVertices is also a glm::vec3 variable]):

```
        // Lower-left vertex
        triangleVertices.push_back(glm::vec3(controlPoints[0].x - 30.0f, controlPoints[0].y + 30.0f, controlPoints[0].z));

        // Lower-right vertex
        triangleVertices.push_back(glm::vec3(controlPoints[0].x + 30.0f, controlPoints[0].y + 30.0f, controlPoints[0].z));

        // Upper-center vertex
        triangleVertices.push_back(glm::vec3(controlPoints[0].x, controlPoints[0].y, controlPoints[0].z));

        // Bind VAO for the triangle
        glBindVertexArray(VAOTriangle);

        // Bind and implement VBO for the triangle
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTriangle);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), triangleVertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Connecting coordinates to shader
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Unbind VAO
        glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Then in my game loop, here's how I do the translation (the model matrix is already getting multiplied to the position in the shader, for which the object is already binded):

```
        glBindVertexArray(VAOTriangle);

        float inputX = 0.0;
        float inputY = 0.0;

        GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
        GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        GLfloat speed = 5.0f * deltaTime;
        glm::vec2 direction;

        for (int i = 0; i < controlPoints.size(); i++)
        {
            inputX = controlPoints[i].x;
            inputY = controlPoints[i].y;
            direction.x = inputX * float((speed * deltaTime) / 1000.0f);
            direction.y = inputY * float((speed * deltaTime) / 1000.0f);

            model_matrix = glm::translate(model_matrix, glm::vec3(direction, 0.0f));    
            glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_matrix));    
        }

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertices.size());


        glBindVertexArray(0);
```

If I put glDrawArrays in the for loop, it creates the same amount of triangles as points, which is not what I want (just 1 triangle). But like this, it looks like it only takes the direction of the last point, since it draws once the entire loop is over. But it doesn't do that either. Like I said, it just goes bottom-right (till its gone from the window) no matter the line structure.

Edit:

Here's my new setup on how to translate the object along the line. It still goes off the line towards the bottom-right direction no matter what I do.

```
        glBindVertexArray(VAOTriangle);

        // Getting time to define translation speed
        GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
        GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        GLfloat speed = 3.0f * deltaTime;

        // Going through all points of the line
        translationX = controlPoints[translationIndex].x;
        translationY = controlPoints[translationIndex].y;

        if (translationIndex < controlPoints.size() - 1)
        {
            translationIndex++;
            translationIndex %= controlPoints.size();
        }

        // Update direction vector
        translationDirection.x = translationX * float((speed * deltaTime) / 1000.0f);
        translationDirection.y = translationY * float((speed * deltaTime) / 1000.0f);
        model_matrix = glm::translate(model_matrix, glm::vec3(translationDirection, 0.0f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_matrix));    
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertices.size());     
        glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through the whole controlPoints array at once and only last call to glUniformMatrix4fv matters.

What you should try to do is removing this for loop and increment some value (each frame or specific step) which will replace your "i" variable.

Comment: So you're saying I remove the loop, and I do:

Comment: So you're saying I remove the loop, define int i = 0 outside of game loop, and I do:

                        inputX = controlPoints[i].x;
   inputY = controlPoints[i].y;
                        i = i + 1;

If so, that crashes the program.

Comment: Do you clamp the value? It should be in range of 0 to controlPoints.size() - 1. Try with i = i % controlPonts.size() after incrementation.

Comment: Ok, now the same thing happens (just moves bottom left), except the triangle gitters, which is worse. Are you sure the rest of my code is fine?

Comment: How often does the index incrementation occur? Is it running as fast as rendering single frame? Keep in mind that this way it could be running 200 FPS so it would mean that your counter reaches maximum value in just a fraction of second.

Since you're already using time getters try adding some "cooldown" for which you will check in that if condition.

Comment: But I already handled the speed of the translation. I don't understand what you mean exactly. After every incrementation, it gets passed into the direction vector with the deltaTime and speed into consideration. I even altered the speed, making the translation very slow, yet still doesn't go along the line. Perhaps show me what you mean so I can get a better understanding.